# Can I put meat on a broiler rack without using foil?

Tags: roasting, broiling

I have a sturdy broiler I use for broiling meat. It is very similar to the [Cook N Home Nonstick Turkey Roaster](http://www.cooknhome.com/item/bake-and-roasting/cook-n-home-02433-nonstick-tur/lid=45334450), a rectangular cast iron deep walled pan with a rack inside of it.

Formerly I have always put foil on the rack when cooking something, but recently I have thought, why not put the meat directly on the rack?

Are there any reasons to use foil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cooking without foil for a week or two my experience is that there are two problems. One problem occurs if you are cooking anything that can fall apart or fragment like fish or stew meat. The pieces can fall through the rack into the pan. The other problem is that without the foil shield the waste oils and fats in the bottom of the pan get hotter and spatter more. Also, without the foil in place it is easier for them to spatter out of the oven onto the cook. So, overall I think foil is probably a better way to go.

Comment: Bear in mind that one of the advantages of broiling is that the fat drips away from the meat, making it a healthier (or at least lower fat) option. If you cover the grid with foil you eliminate that advantage. You may as well just use an oven sheet instead of the broiling pan.